# Android TalkBack: How can I change what TalkBack read aloud when a TimePicker configured with intervals appears?

Tags: android, accessibility, timepicker, talkback

First I click on a button I show a DialogFragment which contains a LinearLayout with a TimePicker in spinner mode with an interval of 15 minutes:

```
public void setIntervals() {
        int numValues = 60 / interval;
        String[] displayedValues = new String[numValues];
        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
            displayedValues[i] = FORMATTER.format(i * interval);
        }

        View minute = timePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("minute", "id", "android"));
        if ((minute != null) && (minute instanceof NumberPicker)) {
            minutePicker = (NumberPicker) minute;
            minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
            minutePicker.setMaxValue(numValues - 1);
            minutePicker.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues);
        }
    }
```

When I activated TalkBack and dialog was opened, TalkBack read, for example, "10:1" instead of "10:15". Same problem every time I changed minute value. I solved the problem with the minute change assigning an AccesibilityDelegate to the TimePicker. But the problem when dialog opens still happens.

```
public class TimePickerAccesibilityDelegate extends AccessibilityDelegateCompat {

        public int hour;
        public int minute;
        public boolean timeChanged = false;

        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
            updateEventContentDescription(event);
        }

        public void setTimeChanged(boolean isChanged) {
            timeChanged = isChanged;
        }

        public void updateEventContentDescription(AccessibilityEvent event){
            ArrayList<Integer> eventTypes;
            eventTypes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT, AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED));
            if ((timeChanged) && eventTypes.contains(event.getEventType())) {
                event.setContentDescription(hour + ":" + FORMATTER.format(minute));
                setTimeChanged(false);

            }
        }

    }
```